# How create an account for myself as administrator (sudo)

Tags: linux, shell

I have sudoer root access and would like to create one new admin account for myself and one regular account without full access!

on the command line I can use $ adduser USERID

I tried $ visudo and changed it manually, but didn't work . is there another way?

but how can I give admin access to this user? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sudo access is granted via the `/etc/sudoers` file, and has nothing to to with making an account.

You can edit `/etc/sudoers` with `sudo visudo`, which will use your $EDITOR to edit the file.

- If you don't want the new user to have any access, don't edit the file.
- If you want then to have limited access you could add a line like `new_user_name ALL=/path/to/some_command, /some/other/command_here`

At which point `sudo some_command` and `sudo command_here` would work, but no other commands would

Comment: thank you, but as I mentioned before I changed it , but didn't work :(

Comment: what do you think about this command $ sudo usermod -a -G admin <username>
$sudo adduser <username> admin